# I've changed the URL and lost my top search result position in Google - would it help to revert the changes?

Tags: seo, google-search, url, 301-redirect

I've changed my top-ranking page to a simpler URL on the same domain with a 301 / permanent redirect, and changed sitemap and internal links accordingly.
A couple of days later Google crawled the site, indexed the new URL and dropped the old one.
My fears became true: despite recognizing the new canonical URL for the old indexed page, the page has vanished from the search results.

Would it help to revert the changes (that would mean that Google has kept some history of the old page rank)?

Comment: Are you sure you have done the configurations totally right? Is your 301 redirect done right? (trace page)
Are snippets and canonical tags edited due to the new change?

Comment: @RezaAtaei Yes, the 301 works correctly. Not sure what you mean by snippets. Don't have a canonical tag because of the redirect and Google designating the new and indexed URL as canonical automatically. The good news is that I'm back amongst the first results, albeit not at the top currently. Might be due to some changes I made on a modal dialog on the page.

Comment: Glad that your rankings are back. Normally it sometimes take time for google to fully take into action the changes. All in all there is no gaurantee that all your rankings would be the same after a 301 redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Surely 301 redirect works in this scenario but it takes some time to regain the old ranking. Even  I had also done the same things on my site a couple of months ago, it took almost 10 or 12 days to regain my ranking.
Note: 10 or 12 days is not mandatory in every case but it took this amount of time in my case. In the conclusion, I just want you to wait for some days and you will see the difference.